# value of 'SET_ATTRIB' must be a pairlist or NULL, not a 'integer'

Tags: rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to implement a crossover operation for a genetic algorithm in Rcpp with RcppArmadillo objects. The code is presented below:

```
cppFunction( 'IntegerMatrix EBD_RS_BR3( arma::umat parents ){

    int nrow = parents.n_rows;
    int ncol = parents.n_cols;

    //Make two temporary matrices
    arma::umat fathers( nrow, ncol );
    arma::umat mothers( nrow, ncol );

    IntegerVector selector(2);

    for ( int i = 0; i < ncol; i ++ ){
        //Sample two columns from *parents* without replacement
        //Subtract 1 so we sample from [0,ncol-1]
        selector = sample( ncol, 2, false )-1;
        //Assign selected columns
        fathers.col(i) = parents.col( selector(0) );
        mothers.col(i) = parents.col( selector(1) );
    }

    // Make an indicator matrix
    arma::umat p = arma::randi<arma::umat>( nrow, ncol, arma::distr_param(0,1) );
    arma::umat return_matrix = p % fathers + (1-p) % mothers;

    return( wrap( return_matrix ) );
}', depends = "RcppArmadillo" )
```

When I run the code multiple times in a loop such as
`system.time( for( i in 1:100000 ){ print(i); EBD_RS_BR3( parents ) } )`
 I sometimes encounter the error:

```
Error in .Primitive(".Call")(<pointer: 0x0000000071282e00>, parents) : 
  value of 'SET_ATTRIB' must be a pairlist or NULL, not a 'integer'
```

and in other cases, I get the error:

```
Error in .Primitive(".Call")(<pointer: 0x0000000071282e00>, parents) : 
    unimplemented type 'NULL' in 'coerceToInteger'
```

and sometimes, Rstudio crashes without reporting anything.

However, I am not able to consistently reproduce this error. May I please have some advice on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I think the issue was with wrapping the `arma::umat` to `IntegerMatrix`.  
Changing the return type to `arma::umat` or adding a line at the end such as `IntegerMatrix z( nrow, ncol, return_matrix.begin()` and returning `z` seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Which makes some sense as `umat` is not something R knows -- it only has signed integers.